Zoom in a Map with GeoPandas
I made a map in Python in Google Colab with GeoPandas and I just want to zoom in on the Europe area, but when I set the axis limits, the
following appears.

I want only the Europe area and change the position of France since it appears in the Spain area.
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Convertir DataFrame a GeoDataFrame
gdf_mundo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_turismoextfinal, geometry='geometry')

# Crear el mapa utilizando GeoPandas
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))

# Crear un subconjunto de datos para los países con valores en la columna 'poblacion'
gdf_merged = gdf_mundo.dropna(subset=['PRODECENCIA EXTRANJEROS'])
gdf_merged.plot(column='PRODECENCIA EXTRANJEROS', cmap='ocean_r', ax=ax, legend=True, legend_kwds={'shrink': 0.5}, alpha=0.8, vmin=0, vmax=5)

# Resaltar los países con datos
gdf_merged.boundary.plot(ax=ax, color='white', linewidth=1)

# Agregar solo el nombre de cada país en el mapa
for idx, row in gdf_merged.iterrows():
    fontsize = 8
    text = row['etiqueta']
    ax.text(row.geometry.centroid.x, row.geometry.centroid.y, text, fontsize=fontsize, ha='center')

# Configurar el título
title = ax.set_title('Población por países, 2022', fontsize=24, pad=20)

# Ajustar el tamaño de letra de la leyenda si existe
legend = ax.get_legend()
if legend is not None:
    plt.setp(legend.get_texts(), fontsize='10')  # for legend text

# Ocultar los ejes y el borde del eje
ax.set_axis_on()

ax.set_xlim([-40, 45])  # Ajustar límites en el eje x según tus necesidades
ax.set_ylim([20, 80])

